# How to code a condition statement in Python for opening websites

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

I want to get the code to open a webpage if the page is not on the default browser. If the page is open on the default browser it will not open the Chrome page. For example if I have a tab open for YouTube, the code will not open a new tab for YouTube. If the browser does not have a tab for YouTube, then the code create a new tab for YouTube.

```
import time
import hashlib
import webbrowser

#product = input("Enter the name of the product you want to buy: ")
webpage = input("Enter the link to the webpage: ")

#get the webpage of the link
webbrowser.get('windows-default').open(webpage)
print("web page opened")
```

Comment: What have you found while doing research about your problem? If you found anything, then you can mention those as well

Comment: As a complement to @Xitiz's comment, i suggest you to read the following guideline: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask